# Can I search by Accept Rate?

Tags: support, search

Is is possible to search by accept rate?

I would like to do some answering, but I like to answer questions of folks who follow up on their questions (call me crazy).

I would like to do something like this:

```
Select AllQuestions 
where  Tag = 'TFS'
       and Asker.AcceptRate > 50%
```

If that cannot be done, can a way to filter based on number of questions asked at rep be made?

Something like:

```
Select AllQuestions 
where  Tag = 'TFS'
       and Asker.NumberOfQuestions >= 5
       and Asker.Reputation < 25
```

That would filter out the users who ask then never come back.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like Users on the Data Explorer contains accept rate data... directly. But you can derive it using the exact same way that accept rate is calculated in the first place! Remember, the qualifications are:

- Question is **at least 3 days old**
- Question is **not Community Wiki**
- Question is **not closed**
- Question has **at least one answer**
- At least **4** such questions must exist for accept rate to be calculated.

So, if you can run a query that tallies up all of the questions that meet those 4 criteria, and then check to see the percentage of questions that have an accepted answer id, you can implicitly determine that user's accept rate. Then, you can add that into a filter of questions to run on the question asker. Don't actually know how complex that really is, but all of that data should be in the Data Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to do some answering, but I like to answer questions of folks who follow up on their questions (call me crazy).

Ok... You're *crazy!*

If you're concerned about rep, don't think about the question's *author*. He can only give you 25 points, no matter how diligent he might be about clicking things next to your answer. It's everyone else reading the question who'll give you *real* arbitrary numbers.

If you're just concerned about feedback, then accept rate doesn't necessarily tell you anything: some users accept answers without any other feedback, while others will happily tell you that you solved their problem and then disappear forever.

Do your best to give good answers to good questions. Don't sweat accept rates.

Comment: Good answer. Accept rates are overrated.

Answer (score 0):

I think filtering out users with 1 rep (or perhaps with < 50) would do much better job, there are not that many users that ignore answers to their questions once they get started on SE, it is usually the 1 rep users that just never accept anything.

Comment: True. Ideally I would filter out the <50 rep users that have more than 5 questions.  (I am fine to give the benefit of the doubt to a first timer.)